# How do I send Bulk data to elasticsearch using log4j2

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j2

I am new to elasticsearch. I need to send bulk data to elasticsearch using log4j2. I didn't find any proper information on the internet for this. Even some informative article would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain "I need to send bulk data to elasticsearch using log4j2" , which data you want to send? applications logs which your logging using logger or something else?

Comment: {"index" : {}}
{"Level":"DEBUG","Package":"com.dci.db4.document.GetDocumentControlTabbar","Message":"############# setting buttons:151 ############"}    This is one sample object

Comment: Ok then given document in ans section will be useful for such data.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoSql Log4j2 appender logs messages to Elasticsearch.

https://github.com/jprante/log4j2-elasticsearch